# Garbage collection eligibility in ruby

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, watir

I have a functional framework to perform web automation testing that uses watir. In that framework there is a module with bunch of methods that perform basic stuff like clicking on objects, setting values in inputs and verifying confirmation messages. So my tests just call those methods from that module and execute them.
My question is, are objects which were created in my methods are eligible for GC or it is better if I implicitly set them to nil?
Here is example from my framework's Module:

```
module Base
 def click(element_hash)
  begin
   obj = @browser.element(element_hash.keys[0],element_hash.values[0])
   obj.when_present.click
   report_pass("Element successfully clicked")
  rescue=>exception
   report_fail("Failed to click on object. #{exception})
 end
end
```

and one of my tests look like this:

```
sample_test_script.rb

include 'Base'
open_browser('url',:ff)
set_input(user_input_hash, 'user1')
set_input(pwd_input_hash, 'test123')
click(sign_in_hash)
verify(success_hash, 'Welcome')
click(acct_hash)
set_input(acct_inp_hash, '3123212321')
click(search_hash)
```

as you can analyze code from above files, is it good idea to set `obj` from `click` method in `Base` module to `nil` to make it eligible fot GC? or it is already eligible for GC after a method is executed in `sample_test_script.rb`?